# One div-Container same height as the other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

my problem sounds like easy but i doesn't found a solution.

I use Bootstrap Grid System and have the following code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            some content            
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            some more content </br></br>...         
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is the the second div is higher then the other, because he contains more content.

How can i bring them to the same height?

Comment: Maybe you can post some CSS?

Comment: Show a jsfiddle so we can edit it.

Comment: There is no CSS. Just the CSS File from Bootstrap v3.1.1 - [click here](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: [matchHeight](http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/) is a great jQuery plugin that can accomplish this.

Comment: If i would use jQuery for this i could write a own 3 line javascript which read the height of the bigger one and add it to the smaller one.
But i just want to use css. Any ideas?

Comment: I finally found a [solution](http://www.bootply.com/i86f08Pt1A) after trying around 2 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Hakan's answer would work, but maybe tying the height of the columns to the height of the row as a whole is a better solution?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var rowHeight = $('.row').height();
   $('.col-md-6').height(rowHeight);
});
```

Here's a JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rxSPG/

(I don't have enough rep to comment, so... ) In response to the table-cell solution, it does work, but setting the divs to `display: table-cell;` will break the responsive bootstrap styles (the divs will not stack on smaller screens.)  I think JS is the only reliable way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the overflow property in CSS. You could clip the content or even cause a scroll bar to be present so the unseen content is accessable. Is this what you might be looking for?

Comment: No sry, i just want that my div's get the same height :)

Comment: You can use the max-height:?px; . Maybe I am confused but do I understand that you want to simply make both divs the same height? If it is really just that simple try the height:?px; styling element and if that does not do it try the max-height I listed above.

Answer (score 0):

use display: table/table-cell if you don't care about ie<=7

```
.row{
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
.col-md-6{
    border: 1px solid;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LByZQ/